# FOLIUM/LEAFLET: GroupedLayerControl doesn't render properly when there is too many layers

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I'm trying to display the routes of different vehicles on the map, and I would like to work with GroupedLayerControl to organise my vehicles depending on the day they work, the characteristics, etc.

The problem is, when I'm using the GroupedLayerControl and there's more vehicles than the number of layers that can be displayed, the layer button is bugged and I can't scroll down to see the rest of the vehicles. But when I try with only LayerControl.add_to(my_map), the button works just fine and I can scroll to see all my vehicles.

[The list of vehicles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpBNa.png)

I tried different parameters but I can't make it work, for example with the image above you have a part of the list, but not the full one (there's around 50 vehicles) and I can't scroll down to click on the checkboxes.

Does anybody know why and if there is a way to fix this issue ? Thank you very much !

Comment: You would more likely have success with that question on the leaflet github.

Comment: It helps us to solve your problem if you could show the code that you have tried so far. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)